# Re-drawing a rectangle object in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm trying to draw a Rectangle object for my game with a different colour so it looks like it's opened.

Basically when I run the program, it should render the doors as grey rectangles and then switch their colour after 10 seconds. They should then 'close', returning back to their original colour, after 3 seconds of being open. However, they start off as the wrong colour and then don't change at all.

I looked into using a state machine to determine whether or not the door object is open or closed, and then calling a method in Draw() to either draw it as a blue rectangle or a grey rectangle.

My enum for _doorStates:

```
enum doorState
    {
        Open,
        Closed,
    }

doorState[] _doorStates = new doorState[50];
```

This is my code in Update() that determines whether or not the door needs to be opened. I have an array of door objects and an array of _doorStates. I know this isn't the most efficient way of doing it but it's a bit late to change it!

```
for (int i = 0; i < doorNumber; i++)
        {
            if (doors[i].doorState == false)//if the object's bool value says it is closed
            {
                if (timeElapsed % doors[i].doorOpenRate == 0 && timeElapsed >= doors[i].doorOpenRate)//is it time for the door to open?
                {
                    doors[i].doorState = true;

                    _doorStates[i] = doorState.Open;

                    timeOpened = timeElapsed;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (timeElapsed - timeOpened == 3)//has it been open for 3 seconds?
                {
                    doors[i].doorState = false;

                    _doorStates[i] = doorState.Closed;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code inside the Draw() method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doorNumber; i++)
        {
            switch(_doorStates[i])
            {
                case doorState.Open:
                    drawOpenDoor(doors[i], gameTime);
                    break;
                case doorState.Closed:
                    drawClosedDoor(doors[i], gameTime);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And these are my separate draw methods:

```
    private void drawOpenDoor(door door, GameTime deltaTime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(rect, door.doorObject, Color.CornflowerBlue);
    }

    private void drawClosedDoor(door door, GameTime deltatime)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(rect, door.doorObject, Color.DarkGray);
    }
```

This is my constructor for the door objects:

```
public door (int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, int orientation, int openRate, int openDuration)
    {
        if (orientation == 0)
        {
            doorObject = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height);
        }

        else
        {
            doorObject = new Rectangle(xPos + 15, yPos, height, width);
        }

        doorOrientation = orientation;//horizontal = 0, vertical = 1
        doorOpenRate = openRate;
        doorOpenDuration = openDuration;
        doorState = false;
    }
```

This is my first post so let me know if you need any more info like how the classes work. I used [this post](http://community.monogame.net/t/switch-scenes-in-monogame/2605) for creating the state machine.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Generally "debug my code" type questions are not well received here but don't let that discourage you [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) takes practice. A quick look at your code and I have a feeling this line: `timeElapsed - timeOpened == 3` has something to do with it. Almost certainly, timeElapsed is going to be a floating point number so comparing it to exactly 3 won't work. Try changing the operator to `>=` and see what happens. There's a pretty good chance there's some other problems but this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Would better questions be more abstract? Like "how do I do this?" instead of "what did I do wrong?"

Comment: @twigonometry Both kind of answers are not wrong in particulair, as long as you've properly explained what you want to do.